# Irregular DIV shape, cross browser platform support

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a irregular shaped DIV, but the only method that I found out to accomplish this is by using the polygon() function. Unfortunately, [IE and FF don't support it](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-shapes). I don't need all versions to be supported, but at least the latest, of IE, FF and Chrome.

What I'm trying to accomplish is basically this - with a black border between the white and the red:

[image: Example]

The white part would be the navigation menu (home, contact, about, etc) and the red portion would be the content, however, I need ALL the red part to be clickable (meaning: I can put a link anywhere and the user can click with ease...)

The end result should look something like this:

[image: Mockup]

Also, the white div needs to maintain the angle independent of the size of the viewport, because the site will be responsive.

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's make the sloped sidebar with a [`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform):

- The sidebar is given `position: fixed` and will stay in one place relative to the viewport
- The sidebar is given `transform: rotate(20deg)` to rotate it and create a sloped shape
- `transform-origin: 100% 0%` helps position the sidebars shape where we want it ([read more on `transform-origin` here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin))
- The nav inside the sidebar is given `transform: rotate(-20deg)` to cancel out the rotation for the text
- Max width / height is used to keep the size of the sidebar flexible but not too large or small

### Example

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #EEE;
}
.sidebar {
  height: 200%;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  min-width: 250px;
  display: block;
  background: #FFF;
  transform: rotate(20deg);
  transform-origin: 100% 0%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  border-right: solid 2px #000;  
}
/*Demo purposes*/

.sidebar > nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 30%;
  width: 300px;
  transform: rotate(-20deg);
}
.sidebar > nav > a {
  display: block;
}
.content {
  background: #CCC;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  <nav>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
  </nav>
</div>

<div class="content">
  I am covered by the sidebar!
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would probably do this with [SVG](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/why-arent-you-using-svg--net-25414), which is [widely supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg). You could also achieve the angled effect with [CSS transformations](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transform/). I'm afraid your question is not specific enough to invite a more detailed answer, but hopefully those links will help you get started.

Comment: Would you kindly elucidate? Perhaps with some examples. Not sure how to get the result I expect, using these methods.

Comment: Maybe this helps? https://www.dropbox.com/s/xm3dfm9kqkralbp/Screenshot%202015-02-23%2022.46.44.png?dl=0

Comment: Thanks for the downvote, really encourages me to "elucidate".

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is the solution you want but you could easily achieve this by simply overlaying a png with an opaque angled white area like the one attached.  It's only 1.8k at 300 x 800px and I don't see why you couldn't scale it or make it responsive with a little effort.

http://zuma-design.com/shared/angle.png